# iOS: People picker inside UIPopoverController, search keyboard distorts popover

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller, abpeoplepickerview

I have a people picker inside a UIPopoverController, since it has a search field, which will trigger the keyboard when tapped, then I got this ugly result:

[image: People picker inside UIPopoverController]

the arrow of the popover is UP which is best look in my app, I also tried to use UP | DOWN but it does not work(still always UP), I know I can use only DOWN arrow instead, but that should be the last solution, I wonder is there any method to deal with this?

Thanks!

update:
I was thinking that can I use UP arrow first, then when the search field becomes first responds(not sure how to detect this), I change it to DOWN arrow(also not sure how to do this)?

update 2:
also the view is not a table or something that can be scrolled, so I cannot scroll the view to make the popover look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, that is quite an ugly resolution.

The problem is that the `UIPopoverController` is coded to avoid colling with the keyboard view.

I think the only way you can work around this is to either create a custom `UIPopoverController` that ignores the keyboard appearing (i believe some listeners needs to be disabled on either the SharedApplication or mainscreen) or make a custom UIView that holds this.